# Access S3 bucket from my EC2 instance using CF::Init via IAM role not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have a CloudFormation template I'm using to set up an ECS cluster and I am trying to drop some config files onto the box using CloudFormation::Init on the ASG and pulling them out of S3.

```
"ECSASGLaunchConfiguration": {
  "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
  "Metadata": {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication": {
      "S3AccessCreds": {
        "type": "S3",
        "roleName": {
          "Ref": "ECSEC2InstanceIAMRole"
        }
      }
    },
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
      "config": {
        "packages": {
        },
        "groups": {
        },
        "users": {
        },
        "sources": {
        },
        "files": {
          "/etc/dd-agent/conf.d/nginx.yaml": {
            "source": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/foobar/scratch/nginx.yaml",
            "mode": "000644",
            "owner": "root",
            "group": "root"
          },
          "/etc/dd-agent/conf.d/docker_daemon.yaml": {
            "source": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/foobar/scratch/docker_daemon.yaml",
            "mode": "000644",
            "owner": "root",
            "group": "root"
          }
        },
        "commands": {
        },
        "services": {
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

To do so, I've added a policy inline to the role I'm creating for my EC2 instances that should allow all S3 access from the instances.

```
"ECSEC2InstanceIAMRole": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
  "Properties": {
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": [
              "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            ]
          },
          "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "ManagedPolicyArns": [
      "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role",
      "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess"
    ],
    "Path": "/",
    "Policies": [
      {
        "PolicyName": "otxS3access",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
              ],
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::foobar"
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
              ],
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::foobar/*"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
"ECSEC2InstanceIAMProfile": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
  "Properties": {
    "Path": "/",
    "Roles": [
      {
        "Ref": "ECSEC2InstanceIAMRole"
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

But it doesn't work.  I can't find an error (or anything else) in the logs. When I manually try to curl it from the instance it doesn't work either, "`AccessDenied`..."

The bucket itself in this case, "foobar", doesn't have any special permissions besides not being public, just the standard account-name single grantee.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you include your aws account number in the ARN?  ...update, S3 does not need account number in the ARN

Comment: Added a AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication stanza (edited in above) - no love.

Comment: It's either not geting a token from the security token service, or its not assuming the role - can you 'printenv' in the EC2 instance to see if the aws access key and secret key are loaded - also does the client have the EC2 tools installed and setup to make the S3 call?

Comment: the token's not in the env, and the aws tools are not loaded, but I didn't think that was required for cloudformation::init (I'm not doing it myself in a script in user-data or whatnot.)   It uses cfn-init, which I am installing in my user-data.  Should work like this: https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx3LKFZ27CWZBKO/Authenticated-File-Downloads-with-CloudFormation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem.  All that CloudFormation in the question is just fine and does what it's supposed to.  The problem was with my run of cfn-init in the instance user-data set up in the ASG's launch configuration  - that wasn't working so it wasn't executing the init stuff.  Thanks to @Rob-d, your comments led me down the path to the executable-level.

The magical other part that makes all this work:

```
    "UserData": {
      "Fn::Base64": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            "#!/bin/bash\n",
            "cat > /etc/ecs/ecs.config <<EOF\n",
            "ECS_CLUSTER=",
            {
              "Ref": "ECSCluster"
            },
            "\n",
            "ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE=docker\n",
            "ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA={REDACTED}\n",
            "EOF\n",
            "yum -y install aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
            "# Install the files and packages from the metadata\n",
            "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
            "         --stack ",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
            },
            "         --resource ECSASGLaunchConfiguration ",
            "         --region ",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::Region"
            },
            "\n",
            "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e -0 ",
            "         --stack ",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
            },
            "         --resource ECSAutoScalingGroup ",
            "         --region ",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::Region"
            },
            "\n",
            "\n"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
```